# Multi-step forms on iOS

Tags: forms, ios, multi-step

Google has material design guidelines for its multi-step forms: https://material.google.com/components/steppers.html#steppers-types-of-steps.

Are there similar guidelines for iOS? If not, are there some de facto standards apps adhere to?

I'm especially curious about the behavior of the back button and if it should be there at all (on Android, this button acts as an "up" button and it wouldn't make sense in a multi-step form, because all the steps are on one level in the screen hierarchy), what the best placement for the stepper is, and whether it should be fixed or scroll with the page.